# File-System to Database(Object Store) sync

Tags: linux, database, frameworks, filesystems, persistent-object-store

I have a use case where I need to back up contents of a directory in a database.

The files (in linux filesystem) should get synced to database (or any object store) periodically or in any other way (something like Copy on Write-COW).
Is there any existing framework available for the same?

One solution is to write a program to sync contents to db and run this as a cron. I am not sure if this is the best solution for the above problem.